# AVPlayer / AVPlayerItem returns playback error too slow

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

If there is no file on the server (or another server error) AVPlayer returns an error for 5-10 seconds. How can I set timeout?

Sample:

```
    let assetKeys = ["playable", "tracks", "duration"]

    asset.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(assetKeys) {
        var loaded = false

        for assetKey in assetKeys {
            var error: NSError?
            let status = asset.statusOfValueForKey(assetKey, error: &error)

            loaded = status == .Loaded
        }

        if !loaded {
            // error in 5-10 sec
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't all code in `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys` closure is called in 5-10 sec?

Answer (score 0):

if on ios9.0+ . 
check Whether AVPlayItem canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused is YES.